# Php Datetime Unknown Format - Date Only

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am working on extracting the date from `filenames`. For this I have used regex.

The dates can appear like `2015-10-31`,`20151031`, `31-10-2015`,`31102015`.

Here is the code I am using to extract the date:

```
$re = '/(\d{8})|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/';
$str = "20151001-importsrc1.txt";
$str = "2015-10-01-importsrc1.txt";
$str = "01-10-2015-importsrc1.txt";
$str = "importsrc1-2015-10-01.txt";
$str = "importsrc1-01102015.txt";
$str = "importsrc1-01-10-2015.txt";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$date = str_replace("-", "", $matches[0]);
```

Using the `str_replace` I am stripping the hyphens, therefore I end up with one of two formats, `20151031`, `31102015`.

Using `strtotime()` it is converting to `1970`. Using PHP's `DateTime` I received the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (01102015) at position 7 (5): Unexpected character'

I need to avoid `createfromformat` from what I understand, but as I only have a date and not datetime this is erroring.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I could format these dates for use later in the code.

Comment: Never mind I understand, some of them happen to have hyphens and some don't.

Comment: You always had this format of date

Comment: `strtotime()` will give you a 1970 date when it does not understand the date format. It does not understand `01012015` and therefore when you remove hyphens it will not undestand `01-01-2015`. It does understand `20150101` however

Answer (score 0):

If you only have those four formats only then you can create a custom function like as

```
function check_format($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/(-?importsrc1-?)|(.txt)/','',$string);
    if (preg_match('/(\d){4}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}/', $string)) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $string);
    } elseif (preg_match('/(\d){2}-(\d){2}-(\d){4}/', $string)) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $string);
    } elseif (preg_match('/..\K(\d{2})/', $string, $m)) {
        if ($m[0] > 12) {
            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $string);
        } else {
            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $string);
        }
    }
        return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/463706)

Comment: Needs a little more. Test it with his actual inputs and it errors

Comment: Yep that can be the case riggs @RiggsFolly

Comment: Thats works a treat. I hope the questioner sees the change

Answer (score 0):

Do not strip hyphens. So, the next code will work fine.

```
$date1 = new \DateTime('31-10-2015');
$date2 = new \DateTime('2015-10-31');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/463030)